# Convert a cell type to DataGridViewCheckBoxCell using c# and bound it to a value

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I am assigning datatable to a datagridview using datasource , i would like to make the column active looks like a checkbox
Ex : if column active equal 0 the checkbox should be unchecked , and the opposite
can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

How is your query to database look like? If you want your column to be checked or unchecked the simplest solution is to convert one of your values in sql query to bit. In C# it will be treated like bool column and it will be presented like checkbox column. For example:

```
public void LoadData(ref DataTable dt)
    {           
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection("your connection string here"))
        {
            connection.Open();                
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT CONVERT(bit, ISNULL(yourSqlColumn which decides, 0)) as Active from yourTable ", connection))
            {                                                               
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dt.Load(reader);
                    reader.Close();                        
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }            
    }
```

In your main form:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        LoadData(ref dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it 
i added a **checkbox** column from designer mode and added the truevalue/falsevalue
then after assigning the datasource i put : 
`grid_dtstock.Columns["clmActive"].DataPropertyName= "active";`
"active" : is the name of my column from mysql
"clmActive" : is the name of the column i've added
thanks any way.